# How can apply custom css style to a table that comes from backend code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used a table (in bootstrap) that look like:
[image]

in **"Static"** page table it is working fine with *td bgcolor* etc.
But in **"Dynamic"** page table its coming from "Text editor", so that the table design is not working because we can't edit the bgcolor for each td. My question is: **"How can apply this type of design into a table with CSS"**

My code:

```css
.txt-red {
    color: #fd5400 !important;
}
.table-light table td {
    border: 1px solid rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.66);
    padding: 8px 8px;
}
.col-black {
    padding: 30px 50px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #cdcdcd;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-black">
<div class="table table-responsive table-light">
  
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="txt-red">
<td bgcolor="#000000">Week</td>
<td bgcolor="#000000">2:30 pm - 1:30 pm</td>
<td bgcolor="#000000">2:30 pm - 1:30 pm</td>
<td bgcolor="#000000">2:30 pm - 1:30 pm</td>
<td bgcolor="#000000">2:30 pm - 1:30 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Sunday</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#1c1c1c">Monday</td>
<td bgcolor="#1c1c1c">Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
<td bgcolor="#1c1c1c">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#1c1c1c">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#1c1c1c">Lorem Ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Tuesday</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#1C1C1C">Tuesday</td>
<td bgcolor="#1C1C1C">Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
<td bgcolor="#1C1C1C">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#1C1C1C">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#1C1C1C">Lorem Ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Tuesday</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#1C1C1C">Tuesday</td>
<td bgcolor="#1C1C1C">Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
<td bgcolor="#1C1C1C">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#1C1C1C">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#1C1C1C">Lorem Ipsum</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Tuesday</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td bgcolor="#333333">Lorem Ipsum</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div></div>
```

Comment: add css class in the backend code where you are generating the table and write css rules for those classes ?

Comment: No, the added code is for only Static html page.... i need the same style with external CSS. Only table comes from backed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the table with external css like this...

```css
.col-black {
  padding: 30px 50px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #cdcdcd;
}
.table-light table td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.66);
  padding: 8px 8px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tbody tr:first-child td {
  color: #fd5400;
}
table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
table tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-black">
  <div class="table table-responsive table-light">

    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Week</td>
          <td>2:30 pm - 1:30 pm</td>
          <td>2:30 pm - 1:30 pm</td>
          <td>2:30 pm - 1:30 pm</td>
          <td>2:30 pm - 1:30 pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sunday</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Monday</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Monday</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Monday</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Monday</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Monday</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Monday</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```